# How to submit form with Ajax and Jquery Validation?

Tags: ajax, jquery-validate

I am trying to submit a from with Ajax and use query validation plugin to validate it . I write code below :

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="school" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>

<script>        
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myForm").validate({ 
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            school: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
    $("#result").html('');
    var values = $(this).serialize();

    $("#myForm").ajaxForm({
        url: "add_admin.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            return $("#myForm").valid();
        },
        success: function(){
            //alert("success");
            $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
        },
        error:function(){
//            alert("failure");
            $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
    });

});

</script>
</body>
```

but it didn't work . Made I any mistake here ?
can any one help me ?
some text some text some text some text some text

Comment: You have `$(this).serialize()` and `event.preventDefault()` inside of your DOM ready event handler function.  Makes absolutely no sense at all... especially since there isn't a `this` to serialize or an `event` to prevent at this location.

Answer (score 1):

**Update : Use following option as it works on all circumstances giving you power of ajax**

[**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/z1nd1ga2/17/)

Check in your NET tab under Inspect element or Firebug

```
   $("#myForm").validate({ 
    rules: {           
        school: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        //Your code for AJAX starts       

        jQuery.ajax({
                     url:'ajax.php',
                     type: "post",
                     data: $(form).serialize(),
                    success: function(){
                        //alert("success");
                        $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
                    },
                    error:function(){
            //            alert("failure");
                        $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
                    }                
        //Your code for AJAX Ends
    });       
  }
```

});

Bottomline -> Use jQuery validate's own mechansim of posting form via AJAX inside ***submitHandler***.

Comment: `didnt work` means ? Did you check NET panel of browser firebug ? What error it gives ? Does form validates well ? If yes then ajax call goes properly ? Paste your HTML too

Comment: Form validation is ok but it cant post my data .

Comment: @DropShadow , can you plese check updated answer and use it in your code ?

Comment: This answer is mostly correct.  However **you are breaking it** with `$(this)`... there is **no such thing as `this` inside of the `submitHandler` option**.  Use the `form` argument provided by the developer.  `$(form).serialize()`

Answer (score -1):

This might help you...

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="school" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="BTNTest" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#myForm").validate({
            onkeyup: false,
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                school: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                }
            }
        });

        event.preventDefault();
        $("#result").html('');
        var values = $(this).serialize();

        $(document).on('click', '#BTNTest', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "add_admin.php",
                type: "post",
                data: values,
                beforeSubmit: function () {
                    return $("#myForm").valid();
                },
                success: function () {
                    //alert("success");
                    $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
                },
                error: function () {
                    //            alert("failure");
                    $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: No.  [As per the jQuery Validate plugin documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler), any `ajax` belongs inside of its `submitHandler` option.  By putting the `ajax` inside of a `click` handler, you're interfering with how the validation plugin operates by default.

Comment: You also have `$(this).serialize()` and `event.preventDefault()` inside of the DOM ready event handler function... makes absolutely no sense at all.