# jQuery Ajax get json returned result

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to get the return result of a php function in an Ajax request in order to make some verification in onSucces. How can I get the JSON result from the php function into the ajax request?

```
public function verifyEmailAction()
{
    $is_valid = true;
    $is_duplicate = false;
    $email_reset = false;

    $register = $this->getRegisterHelper();
    $register->addEmailCheck();
    $register->setData($this->getAllParams());
    $validationErr = $register->getValidationResult();

    if (!empty($validationErr['badWords']['email']) || $validationErr['banned']['email'] == true
        || empty($validationErr['isEmailValid'])
    ) {
        $is_valid = false;
    } elseif (!empty($validationErr['duplicates']['email'])) {
        $is_duplicate = true;
        $email_reset = $this->sendResetEmail();
    }
    $result = [
      'duplicate' => $is_duplicate,
      'valid' => $is_valid,
      'reset' => $email_reset
    ];

    $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($result));
}




jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkDuplicate", function (value, element) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/user/register/verify-email.ajax',
            data: {
                'email': value
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Something like this .success(function(response){ 
            // here is your response            
    })

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit form with Ajax and Jquery Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936749/how-to-submit-form-with-ajax-and-jquery-validation)

Answer (score 1):

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/user/register/verify-email.ajax',
            data: {
                'email': value
            },
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(response){
               console.log(response);
               var duplicate=response.duplicate;
               var valid=response.valid;
               var reset=response.reset;
            },
            error:function(err){
               console.log('Error '+err);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the success and error functions like below,

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkDuplicate", function (value, element) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/user/register/verify-email.ajax',
            data: {
                'email': value
            },
            success : function(data, status, xhr) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage){
                  console.log("ERROR " + errorMessage);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  data: {
   'email': value
  },
  dataType:'json',
  }).success(function(response){ 
        //YOUR Json KEY
        if(response.success){
        }            
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this article will help you.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Specially you can use this

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "YOURURL",
  type: "YOURTYPE",
  dataType:"json",
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data) // to see the reqested data
  // manipulate data here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType:'json'`:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkDuplicate", function (value, element) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/user/register/verify-email.ajax',
            data: {
                'email': value
            },
            dataType:'json'
        });
    });
```

You can use this to convert JSON string to a JavaScript object:

```
var txtReturned = JSON.parse(data);
```

---

#### Reference:

- [jQuery AJAX Call to PHP Script with JSON Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155192/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)